# Can locales be used to switch layouts?

Tags: localization

In my particular case I need to be able to switch the layout that the template extends. Is this possible to do using locales?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untested, but should be fairly straightforward.

```
{% if craft.locale == 'de' %}
    {% set template = '_layout_de.html' %}
{% else %}
    {% set template = '_layout.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% extends template %}
```

or

```
{% extends craft.locale == 'de' ? '_layout_de.html' : '_layout.html' %}
```

or using a locale folder (thank josh baker)

```
{% extends craft.locale ~ '/_layout' %}
```

Comment: You might also use string concatenation, which makes adding new layouts easier in future. For example `{% extends craft.locale ~ '/_layout' %}` would point to `/templates/en/_layout`.

Comment: Great addition @JoshBaker

Comment: When I try that I get a "Multiple extends tags are forbidden" message returned. Something to do with the processing order perhaps where it's evaluating `extends` before the conditional construct?

Comment: Most likely just doesn't like the multiple extends statements. I modified the example using a single extends and variables. Also, did you try one of the other methods?

Comment: The error message gave it away. :) In my case your other suggestion wouldn't fit my particular use case as it could be one of several and not just one or the other. I didn't notice Josh's suggestion though but it was the kind of pseudo logic I had in my head without quite knowing how to apply it. I've given it a try though and successfully got it to work along (with a slight tweak for my particular template folder structure: `{% extends "layouts/" ~ craft.locale ~ '/layout-name' %}`. Many thanks for the help and suggestions.